# How to clean memory for property?

Tags: c#, mvvm

For a property in ViewModel, a property could be defined as(c#):
private MyClass _myclass;

```
public MyClass Myclass{
   get { return _myclass;}
   set { 
      if(value!=_myclass)
      {
         _myclass = value
         RaisePropertyChanged("Myclass"); 
         // do something else.....
      }  
    }
}
```

Then I want to release the memory when the instance is not used any more. what is the right way?

```
_myclass = null;
RaisePropertyChanged("Myclass");
```

or

```
Myclass = null;
```

or

```
_myclass = null;
Myclass = null;
```

Comment: If instance is not used anymore (any code does not reference it) it will be GCed automatically so you do not need assign `null` yourself, if MyClass uses some resources like files implement IDisposable and dispose explicitly

Comment: .NET uses a garbage collector. This means you do not need to manage your own memory as you would for a C or C++ application.

Comment: I think the title 'How to clean memory for a private field associated with a property' would be more accurate.

Comment: If there are some event handlers hooking up, it needs to be released manually. Also if you don't set instnaces to null and wait for GC, maybe it's too slowly and needs to wait for long time, but users don't wait for such long time when they use the app and open and close controls/components.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really determine when the memory for your object will be freed (that's for the garbage collector to decide), but of course it will only be freed if there are no more references to it. You should set it to null by using the Property set accessor. It will raise the change notification for you.

```
Myclass = null;
```

Note: This applies to pure managed classes. If your class uses unmanaged resources, you would need to implement IDisposable.

Answer (score 0):

Your second option should work fine.

```
Myclass = null;
```

The first option is unnecessarily non-DRY. And the third option won't raise `PorpertyChanged`.